# Minify script in package.json never finishes executing

Tags: npm, package.json, uglifyjs

I want to minify/uglify a javascript file but after I run the script it never finishes executing. These are the scripts and dependencies I added to it.

```
"scripts": {
    "minify": "uglifyjs -i src/*.js -o build/scripts.min.js",
    "uglify": "npm run minify",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.29"
}
```

This is the link to the [package.json](https://github.com/labanino/sarasota-soccer-club/blob/main/package.json) in my repo. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you would not upgrade the version? I mean if it's not a existing project than you can use the latest version.Also I would suggest you to pass -c to script and that should solve your problem

Comment: Yes, it was an old version! Thanks